# Is Pandas DataFrame apply method supposed to execute twice on row of DataFrame with length 1?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

The code below illustrates the problem. The method a() simply adds one to the first column in the dataframe defined. In Out[5] you can see that the output is twice the input value, which leads me to believe that the function is called twice for some reason. Am I missing something here?

You can see in lines [10] and [11] that the function correctly only adds 1 to the first column. Is this in a bug in pandas or am I missing something? I didn't see anything in the documentation about changed behavior based on the length of the Dataframe.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(data={"a":[1],"b":[2]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   a  b
0  1  2

In [4]: def a(row):
   ...:     row["a"] = row["a"] + 1
   ...:     return row
   ...: 

In [5]: df.apply(a, axis=1)
Out[5]: 
   a  b
0  3  2

In [9]: df1 = df.append(df)

In [10]: df1
Out[10]: 
   a  b
0  3  2
0  3  2

In [11]: df1.apply(a, axis=1)
Out[11]: 
   a  b
0  4  2
0  4  2
```

The function that I'm trying to fix actually affects two columns, more akin to below:

```
def a(row):
     row["a"] = row["a"] + 1
     row["b"] = row["b"] + 2
     return row
```

Is there a simple way of fixing that?

Comment: `apply` always does the first group twice to determine if the rest of the groups can be evaluated with a faster code path. this is why with `apply`, you should never modify anything inplace

Comment: for your purposes, if you really want to increment the values by a constant, you should do e.g., `df = df.assign(a=df['a'] + 1)`

Comment: Thanks! The information you provided was super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"a":[1],"b":[2],'c': [3]})

def a(row):
    row['a'] += 1
    row['b'] += 5
    return row

df = df.apply(lambda row : a(row) , axis = 1)
print(df)

#Output: 

   a  b  c
0  2  7  3
```

Comment: I've added an edit to my original question, what if the function changes two columns in the dataframe?

Comment: When I run this the function appears to still apply twice :(
```python

print(df)

# Output:

   a   b  c
0  3  12  3
```

Comment: I don't have that problem. Can you please copy verbatim then run?

Comment: Yes, I copy and pasted and still have the problem.
pandas version = '1.0.3'
Python 3.8.1

Comment: Maybe you should upgrade your pandas mine is 1.2.0

Comment: Testing on 1.2.0 and I get the same output as you. Unfortunately, in my actual environment I can't upgrade but thanks anyways!